# forecast() 'start' TypeError unexpected keyword argument even after pd.to_datetime applied

Tags: python, datetime, arima

**Definition & Problem**

Created function to have arguments passed in and compute forecast using start_date & end_date inside arima_station_forecast() function. I have placed debug print() statements in the function for auditing values station, measure, s_date, e_date; all look fine on inspection. If timetk can work with start_date = '2013-01', end_date = '2016-06', then certainly arima(,... start_date, end_date) can do so also. Therefore, that is what I sent to my function 'arima_station_forecast(,...s_date, e_date) 2018-01
2018-02 data to perform a range forecast(start='2018-01', end='2018-02').

**Question to Solve on forecast()**

Then why and what is the forecast() keyword receiving an unexpected argument for start_date, when forecast(start='2018-01', end='2018-02') values are valid date(s) and the data exists in data set? Is it possible that some data does not have dates? I filtered NA on dates in dataset, so that should not be the problem.

**Arima Station Forecast function**

```
def arima_station_forecast(station, measure, s_date, e_date):
  print(station); print(measure); print(s_date); print(e_date)  
  
  wdata = wd.weather_data.loc[wd.weather_data['callsign'] == station]
  model = statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(wdata[measure], order=(2,1,1))
  model_fit = model.fit()
  model_forecast = model_fit.forecast(5, start=s_date, end=e_date)

  # For example: 
  # model_forecast = model_fit.forecast(5, start='2018-01', end='2018-02')
  return model_forecast

# print of function IN parameters 
Aberdeen, SD
prcp
2018-01
2018-02
```

**MonthEnd import and start/end data config**

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
end_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date, format="%Y%m") + MonthEnd(2)
start_date = start_date.to_period("M")
end_date = end_date.to_period('M')

print(start_date); print(end_date)

2018-01
2018-02
```

**Invoke function and error type on start keyword**

What then is the unexpected keyword argument 'start' seeking? It has been defined as 2018-01, 2018-02, respectively.

```
station = 'Aberdeen, SD'
measure = 'prcp'
result3 = arima_station_forecast(station, measure, start_date, end_date)
# For example:
# result3 = arima_station_forecast('Aberdeen, SD', start='2018-01', end='2018-02'


# result: error
<ipython-input-32-13df922c827b> in arima_station_forecast(station, measure, s_date, e_date)
      5   model = statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(wdata[measure], order=(2,1,1))
      6   model_fit = model.fit()
----> 7   model_forecast = model_fit.forecast(5, start=s_date, end=e_date)
      8 
      9   return model_forecast

TypeError: forecast() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start'
```

**Data Sample**

```
    callsign    date    tavg    tmin    tmax    prcp    snow    wdir    wspd    pres
0   Aberdeen, SD    2018-01-01  -29.1   -35.5   -22.7   0.0 50.0    201.000000  10.1    1046.6
```

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear The [Documentation for ARIMARESULTS.forecast](https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.11.1/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html) show that the input parameters for `.forecast()` are `ARIMAResults.forecast(steps=1, exog=None, alpha=0.05)`. None of these parameters are `start`. Can you show where you are seeing start as an input parameter to forecast?

Comment: My attempt is to setup forecast() with start='2018-01', end='2018-02' on the fit model from arima()

Comment: Yes, for ARIMAResults.forecast(steps=1, exog=None, alpha=0.05). None of these parameters are start). There is a dates array optional array-like object of datetime objects, but I'm not doing dates inside ARIMA, but in forecast() which has a optional start_date and end_date. I hope not to confuse on the purpose for this question.